# Sample -- test -- data for large WordPress install

Tags: plugin-development, database, performance, import, testing

I'm working on a plugin, [Index WP MySQL for Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/). For testing it would be helpful to have a very large WordPress installation containing many thousands of posts, pages, metadata entries, media items, users, options, and so forth. The meaning of the data doesn't matter -- it can be lorem ipsum text -- but having a lot of it would be great.  For my purposes I don't care whether the media files in wp-content/uploads are available. I just want to bring my test installation's MySQL database server to its knees.

It would be great if it were a WooCommerce test site.

(I'm aware of the theme unit test data file at https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xml. But it's not big enough for my specific purpose.)

Is there some such importable dataset available? Is there some sort of tool I can leave running for many hours to generate random data? If it comes to that, how would I create such an automated content production tool?

If I must generate my own load test dataset I'll definitely GPL it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few built-in wp-cli generate commands from the docs:

```
# Generate posts with fetched content. 
# See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/generate/
$ curl -N http://loripsum.net/api/5 | wp post generate --post_content --count=10

# Add meta to every generated term.
# See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/term/generate/
$ wp term generate category --format=ids --count=3 | xargs -d ' ' -I % wp term meta add % foo bar

# Add meta to every generated comment.
# See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/generate/
$ wp comment generate --format=ids --count=3 | xargs -d ' ' -I % wp comment meta add % foo bar

# Add meta to every generated users.
# See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/generate/
$ wp user generate --format=ids --count=3 | xargs -d ' ' -I % wp user meta add % foo bar
```

You can also write your own wp-cli package.

Then there are custom wp-cli packages like [wp-cli-faker](https://github.com/Yoast/wp-cli-faker) (I'm unrelated to it).

Comment: Thanks for sharing about wp-cli-faker. Pretty handy.

Comment: Glad you find it useful.